# Dynamic data display - zoom in map

Tags: c#, memory, dictionary, out-of-memory, dynamic-data-display

I used microsoft visual studio 2010, including reference Dynamic data display chart map - chartplotter. 
The tool zoom in comes with the map tools by wheel.
until now it works perfect, zoom in and out. Suddnly, When I zoom in the project stuck with an error :

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

Any one know how to fix it ? Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: can you show some code please?

Comment: Use a memory profiler.

Comment: it is pritty like 5000 lines of code.. Im doesnt touch the wheel  zoom in.. What can it be ? 
What it is a memory profiler ? can you explain me what to do ? what to write?